# Why don't I get a new refresh token when I refresh an access token in Salesforce?

Tags: rest-api, oauth

When I first authenticate to Salesforce, I get an access token and a refresh token. But if the access token has expired I make a call using the refresh token to get a new access token, but in the response there is no new refresh token.

Is that correct? Does the refresh token never expire for Salesforce?

Here is the call I am making to get a new access token using the refresh call.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://myOrg.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("refresh_token", {currentRefreshToken}, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("client_id", {clientId}, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", {clientsecret}, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I would have expected a new Refresh token in the response.

Comment: Can you please add a snapshot of error/results you got when you tried to make a call, it should be "Session expired or invalid" and also you can check in Setup | Session settings for session timout whether it is set to some random value or never expire(not sure). Also check if you have set the right url/org instance.

Comment: the above does return a json result , except in the result there is no refresh_token. Does the refersh token get refreshed in this stage . So when a user request a new access token using the refresh token , do they get a refreshed refresh token , thats what im asking ? Or do they only get a refresh token when they call the grant_type = authorization_code" ?

Comment: Refresh token is used to get the access token. Refer the this article  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: yes grant_type = authorization_code along with consumer_key and client_secret

Comment: ok let me rephrase it. Does the refresh token ever expire ?

Comment: refresh tokens are valid until you revoke, that is why i asked why you were trying to get another... was there any error?

Comment: Access Token - have limited lifetime specified by session timeout, a refresh token would be provided during authorization which can be used to get a new access token if expired. For example, you login to an app using credentials, but it keeps you logged in becoz of refresh tokens.

Answer (score 5):

Access Tokens are governed through the global [Session Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_sessions.htm&type=5) or the [Profile Session Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_profiles_session.htm&type=5), while Refresh Tokens are controlled via [OAuth Access Policies](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage_oauth.htm&type=5). You simply reuse a Refresh Token as long as it is valid, which can be one of: "until revoked", "immediately", "inactive for *x* time", or "until *x* time has passed". If you lose the Refresh Token, it is expired, or revoked, the user will need to log in again. At this point, you would receive a new Refresh Token as part of the login flow. Note that Refresh Tokens will survive password resets, Security Token resets, and changing the username entirely. This makes them very durable for the purposes of maintaining a session in an app.